# How to pass uniform array of struct to shader via C++ code

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, shader

for eg.
in FragmentShader:-

```
struct LightSource
{
        int Type;
        vec3 Position;
        vec3 Attenuation;
        vec3 Direction;
        vec3 Color;
};

uniform LightSource Light[4];

main(){
        //somecode
}
```

Now how can i send values for `Light[4]`.

Comment: Is this for OpenGL or OpenGL ES? In GL (3.1+), the best way to do this would be with a Uniform Buffer.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman can i use it with GLES 2.0 ?

Comment: No, and that is why I was asking you to be more specific with your tags. You have this tagged for ES and GL.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You will need to get the location of each field of the struct for each array element and send the value separately. See the OpenGL wiki page for reference: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)#Uniform_management.

For example to set the value of Light[0].Type you would do the following:

```
GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program_id, "Light[0].Type");
glUniform1i(loc, value);
```